# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\sin(kx)|}}$ converges a.e (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Solution:

Note that if we fix $x \neq 2\pi n$ for all integers $n$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\sin(kx)|}}$ is bounded by some constant $C$. Also note that the periodicity of sin$(x)$ means that such a constant exists that the expression is bounded for all $k$. Thus we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\sin(kx)|}} \leq C\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

and the right hand side clearly converges. Noting that the set of $x$ that are integer multiples of $\pi$ has measure zero, the result has been shown.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect. There is not a uniform bound on $\sin(kx)$ - what happens if $kx$ happens to be *very* close to an integer multiple of $\pi$? In fact, $kx$ is guaranteed to get arbitrarily close to multiples of $\pi$ as $k$ grows, so this argument cannot work. You need to know something about rational approximation of $\pi$.

Comment: @user296602 Yes, that it was I was afraid of. Thank you, I will look into this!

Comment: If you're interested, a related concept is [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrationality_measure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f_k(x)=\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\sin(kx)|}}$. By the change of variable $kt=u$, we get 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{|\sin(kt)|}}=\frac{1}{k}\int_0^{2\pi k}\frac{du}{\sqrt{|\sin(u)|}}=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{du}{\sqrt{|\sin(u)|}}$$
and that the last integral is finite.
Hence the series $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi}|f_k(t)|dt=\int_0^{2\pi}f_k(t)dt=u_k$ is convergent. By a known result, this imply that the sum $\displaystyle \sum f_k(x)=f(x)$ is in $L^1([0,2\pi])$, hence finite a.e.

Comment: Questions:
1) How do we know the integral is finite?
2) Why is it enough that $f(x)$ is in $L^1[0,2\pi]$, as opposed to on the whole real line? All that says is that it is finite on $[0,2\pi]$ right?

Comment: For the convergence of the integral at $0$, use that $\sin(u)$ is equivalent to $u$, and that the integral $\int_0^1\frac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$ is onvergent, and do the same for $u=\pi,2\pi$. For the second question, Let $A_n$ the subset of $[2n\pi,(2n+2)\pi]$ where the sum is divergent; Then $A_n$ is of zero measure, and $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} A_n$ is of zero measure also.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that the exceptional set $E$ given by

$$ E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\,\left|\sin(nx)\right|\leq n^{-2+\frac{1}{9}}\text{ holds for infinite values of } n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$$ has measure zero. $\pi$ is a trascendental number with a finite [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html): by invoking Salikov's (2008) result we have that
$$ \left|\pi-\frac{p}{q}\right|\leq \frac{1}{q^8} $$
holds just for a finite number of $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}^+$. By considering some $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \pi\mathbb{Z}$ and the convergents of its continued fraction, then by exploiting the Lipschitz-continuity of $f(z)=\sin z$, we have that $E$ is given by a neighbourhood of $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ with measure zero, hence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2\sqrt{|\sin(nx)|}} $$
is a.e. absolutely convergent by asymptotic comparison with $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{1+1/18}}$, which is convergent.